# Undefined identifiers with glfw

Tags: c++, glfw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <math.h>

const GLchar* vertex120 = R"END(
#version 120
uniform mat4 matrix;
attribute vec4 inColor;
attribute vec4 inPosition;
varying vec4 outColor;
void main()
{
    outColor = inColor;
    gl_Position = matrix * inPosition;
}
)END";

int main() {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "Init error";
        exit(-1);
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "Hello", 0, 0);
    if (!window) {
        std::cout << "Window creation error";
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(-1);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertex120, 0);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLint compilationStatus;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPLIE_STATUS, &compilationStatus);
    if (compilationStatus == GL_FALSE) {
        GLchar message[256];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, sizeof(message), 0, &message[0]);
        std::cout << message;
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) { 

        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

I am following a tutorial on using opengl, everything was working out until the above code where I get undefined errors for GLchar*, glCreateShader, glShaderSource. Everything else works so I wasn't able to figure out whats wrong please help.

Comment: Please add the exact error message.

Comment: There is no error message, they are undefined. For some reason including glfw dosen't let me use those functions.

Comment: What are _"undefined errors"_?

Comment: I get identifier "glCreateShader" is undefined, the same for all. I searched the header files and wasn't able to find the functions in there.

Comment: @AlpOrgun Well, that *is* the error message.

Comment: Can you link the tutorial you're using? Normally you should be using something like GLEW or GLAD (in addition to GLFW) for OpenGL.

Comment: Its offline on my computer, no link unfortunately but it only got me to install glfw3 nothing else. Everything worked up to this particular part. I was able to render a triangel and a circle. I linked the glfw3 libs and headers inside vs. I'll try installing GLEW to see if it helps

Comment: from the little research I did I do not thing I should be needing anythign else other then GLFW for this to work not sure tho.

Comment: Okay after some pain trying to install glew I got it working! Thank you :)

Comment: When you say that you "get" `identifier "glCreateShader" is undefined`? What exactly does that mean? Are you seeing that text on your screen somewhere? What do you mean when you say that there "is not error message"? The same thing that says  `identifier "glCreateShader" is undefined` doesn't say **anything** else? really? It doesn't, for example, mention a line number or a file name? What exactly was the process you followed in order to see the message in question?

Comment: The problem is solved now but thank you for the messages. I had that exact error for multiple different functions with "glCreateShader" being the function name. Apparently I needed GLEW for it to all work which was not shown in the tutorial I was following.

Comment: I'm trying to help you, for the future, to understand how to identify and provide "error messages" that allow other people to actually understand what you are talking about.

Comment: I'll make sure to keep that in mind. Thank you! I don't have very much experience on here so I get that I might come off rude or unclear but I am very grateful for the help thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL is implemented by the graphics driver as a bunch of functions implemented, not as a standalone library, therefore cannot be simply linked to your project. To call a function you have to ask OpenGL for a pointer to that function and you have to do that with all the functions you will call.

You can do that by functions such as GetProcAddress... but it depends on the platform you're developing for. to get the function pointer for all that functions it's an exhausting work, for that, there is some libraries like GLEW/GLAD to do that at runtime from the driver for each OpenGL function.

so this is what exactly happens with your code, your program does not know what is this glCreateShader, to fix this you only need the magic line in your code which is

```
 #include <gl/glew.h>
 #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

> note that you need to include GLEW before GLFW. and your program will recognize the functions.

also you have to initialize GLEW after you create the context, you can do it by:

```
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; //to avoid using the deprecated GL functions
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cerr << "GLEW::Error : failed to initialize GLEW"<< std::endl;
    }
```

**And don't forget the library linking part**. I found here a tutorial to install GLEW with visual studio  http://www.mcihanozer.com/tips/setting-up-libraries/setting-up-glew-for-visual-studio/  and to download GLEW http://glew.sourceforge.net/

> PS: to use GLEW as dynamic library (DLL) may raise some problems, if that the case you can use the static version, and that is by typing #define GLEW_STATIC at the beginning of your code and at the linking put the static version of the library. this is just an example with GLEW which is a bit older than GLAD, if you wish to use GLAD it is also a great option.